# How to cast parcelable array list to array list of objects that implement parcelable?

Tags: android, arraylist, casting, parcelable

I have a class cholesterolMonitor that implements parcelable.

In my cholesterolMonitor:

```
 @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    }
 @Override
        public CholesterolMonitor createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new CholesterolMonitor(in);
        }
```

But everytime I try to cast it into an array list of monitors I get an error?For example in one method:

```
this.objectList= (ArrayList<Monitor>) getArguments().getParcelableArrayList(listKey);
```

I get inconvertible type: cannot cast array list of parcelable to array list of monitors?

After Googling I know why, but I'm not sure how to fix it.

Comment: Monitors is also parcelable?

Comment: Sorry I meant casting cholesterol monitor as a parcelable. For example, if I have a method that returns an array list of parcelable and I call that method and assign it to an array list of cholesterol monitors it will return error as an array list of cholesterol monitors is not the same as an array list of parceable eventhough cholesterol monitor implements parcelable.